# To transfer money between banks, is it better to withdraw or deposit?

Tags: banking, money-transfer

If I'm transferring money from Bank A to Bank B, I have multiple options:

- Tell Bank A to deposit the money into my account in Bank B.
- Tell Bank B to withdraw the money from my account in Bank A.

Assuming I can do whichever I like, is there *any reason at all* (however small it might be) to prefer one over the other, whether in terms of security or in terms of convenience or anything else?

Comment: What makes you think it makes any difference?

Comment: @JohnFx: The fact that two different ways of accomplishing the same goal exist makes me wonder if there might be a difference between the two.

Comment: I'm curious: in what country and through what means would you be able, as an individual, to withdraw money from an account held at another bank, by means other than a debit card?

Comment: Also, are you considering the two accounts to be in the same country, using the same currency?

Comment: @jcaron: This is possible in the United States, and yes.

Comment: @jcaron : it is also possible in the European Union. - maybe it did not become clear enough that you of course need to provide credentials to that account - it is certainly not so easy to pull from just *any* account, I should hope.

Comment: As an individual, i.e. not a company with direct debit facilities, and no card merchant account? Other than a good old check? What would be the name of that service? How would you go about providing credentials?

Comment: @jcaron: As an individual all you need to do is to tell the withdrawing bank your account and routing numbers for the other bank that has your money. That's the same information that a good old check contains. It's their job to verity the account is yours, which they usually do by making two small deposits and asking you to confirm the amounts. They then withdraw the money from the other account.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I've seen Paypal do that, but that's a specific case of a payment services provider (ab)using their direct debit/ACH facility. Do other "regular" banks allow you to do this?

Comment: @jcaron: Yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming neither one charges a fee and you are talking about automated non-cash, non-check transactions:

Withdrawal is slightly better if you are 100% sure you have the money (or better yet, twice the money) to cover it.  It puts more incentive on the bank that is responsible for the act to do it correctly, because they will then be the bank holding the money.  It also creates an added check because there is no possibility of having an error in transfer information result in sending your money to the wrong account.  (This is unlikely anyway, but not impossible depending on the bank and interface).

Deposit may be slightly better if you are not, or if you are concerned about technical foul-ups at the bank.  Depending on the bank, a deposit with insufficient funds may be cancelled rather than going through and *then* being cancelled, which could result in various banking fees (returned item fees, overdraft fees, etc...).

If there is a technical foul-up during a withdrawal, you run the risk of having banks get confused--I know of a case where it took a major bank months to fix a withdrawal transaction that was denied the second time when they activated it twice, but the account balance mistakenly showed an extra thousand dollars for the duration.

Comment: +1 thank you, this is precisely the kind of answer I was hoping for.

Comment: Also another note: it looks a lot sketchier for a withdrawal to bounce than for a deposit to not go through due to insufficient funds. Your account might get locked for some time and you might have to explain what happened on another business day. So you might want to prefer depositing here.